# IFormatProvider with Integer value

Tags: c#, iformatprovider

I have an Integer value in my object. I need to cast it as an integer value. So I have done it this way.
System.Convert.ToInt64(Object)
But FxCop said that I need to provide with IFormatProvider. String data type I have no issue with provide IFormatProvider. How can I provide an IFormatProvider for integer value?

Comment: I don't think an `IFormatProvider` is needed here, you can convert it directly.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how you need to print your value.

e.g. using:

```
var provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

you will get a string that is independent from your local (regional) settings.

Using:

```
var provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

or:

```
var provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
```

instead, the string will be printed using your local (regional) machine settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Current Culture

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat
```

or ex:

```
new CultureInfo("en-UK").NumberFormat
```

Comment: Generates error: `new CultureInfo("en-UK").NumberFormat 'new CultureInfo("en-UK")' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo`.... It should be like this: `new CultureInfo("en-GB").NumberFormat` or `new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat`

Answer (score 1):

see here: [IFormatProvider Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem with just casting the object variable?

```
Int64 i = (Int64) myObject;
```

If it really is just a boxed integer, I don't see why that wouldn't work.